# How to split a rails container into a ruby and node containers?

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, docker, version-control, docker-compose

I have a rails 6 app running with ruby 2.6.5 and dependant of node 8. I've been having problems to install node 8 in new releases from the alpine ruby image. I would like to know if it is possible to split the rails app into a ruby and a node container where i can get full independency to version control. I'm currently using the setup describe by the evil martians in here:

https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/ruby-on-whales-docker-for-ruby-rails-development

With some mixed ideas from here:

https://dev.to/hint/rails-development-with-docker-13np

And it has worked for other projects. I've tried buildpacks but they make a single image of the whole app and i want the pieces separated. I have redis, postgres and sidekiq running with this app. My only problem is the node dependency inside my ruby image, i want to separate it. Can it be done?

Comment: I may be reading this wrong, but it's hard to answer your question without more details on that node dependency. If for some reason your Ruby image needs Node to run, then the answer is obviously no. If you have a natural split between a Node server and a Ruby process, then it's definitely possible, but you're not providing enough info.

Comment: Ruby doesn't need node, but the framework rails does. Then the common setup is to just install nodejs and yarn into the ruby container.